# signalR can not register a connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

the project i have to work with is written in MVC3,there is no startup.class and its running on the server smoothly,but on my own pc when i want to run it i get the  error from this part:

```
 signalR.hub = {
    start: function () {
        // This will get replaced with the real hub connection start method when hubs is referenced correctly
        throw new Error("SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/js'></script>.");
    }
};
```

i have the signalr/hubs refrence in the project but no idea why i its not working,any idea?

Answer (score 0):

A script reference to /signalr/js (as the error says) is made?

Comment: yes it is, <script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>

Comment: Check the developer tools in your browser and check for errors on that uri.
If no errors check the content too (see if there's anything in it)

Comment: in there its says error 404,for the signalr/hubs refrence

Comment: Try the full url. Since it is now hosted

Comment: @MichaelBeuving what do you mean?

Comment: The signalR url should point to the location(server) where the hub is hosted, not the client. ~/ will work only when the root and client are in the same folder. Since you now run it on your PC the host adres is probably changed and no longer pointing to the same dir. If you 'start' your project do you get an localhost url?

Comment: @MichaelBeuving when i run it its on the local host on my pc,you mean i should write the server address in order to test it??

Comment: It should point to the URL that hosts the server side hubs. If that is you PC than use the full URL, not the ~/ one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186419/discussion-between-mortezasol-and-michael-beuving).

Comment: You must initialize the hubs in your application_start event via `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()`